# Android ndk-build for Unity3d x86 and Arm.. Build for multiple architectures into one .so file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I'm building a native C++ library for Android, for use with a Unity 3d project.
I want to build for arm and x86, so I set this in application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all
```

This gives me several seperate .so files. Unfortunately currently the way to include an native android library in a unity app is to add the library to the folder assets\Plugins\Android.
I can only put one file with the libraries name in that folder. So i can only have one of the .so files in there. 
Is there any way of merging them into one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put multiple .so files, one for each architecture, into the Plugins/Assets folder, per the [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html):

> For specific Android platform (armv7, x86), the libraries (lib*.so) should be placed in the following:
>
> Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/x86/
>
> Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/

Comment: warning : Unity only recognizes the above folders.
APP_ABI := all also implies mips, mips64, x86_64 and arm64-v8a  architectures which are not recognized by Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Merging multiple architectures into a single .so can't be done on Linux.

That requires [fat binrary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary#FatELF:_Universal_Binaries_for_Linux) support, and the FatELF project is now dead.